# Substitute to MenuCompat.setShowAsAction() on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, compatibility

While searching for a way to show an option in the ActionBar and still be compatible with Honey I came across the MenuCompat.setShowAsAction() method from the compatibility library (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuCompat.html), but it is deprecated and I can't find a substitute in the library to do the same thing. Any Ideas?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read [the JavaDocs for `setShowAsAction()` on `MenuCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuCompat.html#setShowAsAction%28android.view.MenuItem,%20int%29) at the page you linked to above, you will find your answer:

> Use [MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(MenuItem, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setShowAsAction%28android.view.MenuItem,%20int%29)

Comment: Wow, that wasn't there before... Thanks for pointing me, my bad

Comment: 2020 update: Passing `MenuItem` is deprecated now. Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction(int)

Answer (score 6):

`MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(MenuItem, int)` has been deprecated in [API level 26.0.0 beta1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setShowAsAction(android.view.MenuItem%2C%20int)). Now you can use `setShowAsAction (int actionEnum)` directly. `actionEnum` defines how the item should display. You can selecte one of `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS`, `SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM`, or `SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER`. `SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER` is the default. In this example we will use:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_quit), 1)
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_quit).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You know what "1" stands for? I know it right now but tomorrow I've forgotten... Use MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM...